# Como conecto mi aplicación android a una Base de Datos MySQL en android studio?

Tags: java, android, mysql

Me podrían explicar como me puedo conectar a una base de datos en `android` studio, en `java` es tan fácil como descargar una librería y poner

```
public Connection getConexion(){
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/baseDeDatos","root","clave");
            return con;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al conectarse con la BD: "+e.getMessage());
        }
        return con;
    }
```

pero veo que en android es muy diferente.
¿Me pueden decir paso por paso que debo hacer?, Ya tengo descargado `Xamp`.
¿Qué librería necesito?
¿Cómo es la clase?
en caso de utilizar librería, ¿Cómo la coloco en el proyecto?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Por lo que vea necesitas conectar tu base de datos MySQL con Android. Pero lamentablemente esto no es posible. Android no soporta a MySQL como motor de base de datos para instalarlo. La única solución que tienes es hacer un web service que debes consumir en tu aplicacion Android y desde este web service consultar a tu base de datos MySQL.

Otro punto importante es que para hacer persistencia (mantener los valores de tu base de datos MySQL en tu aplicación Android para manejar, mantener, etc) es que hagas una Base de datos SQLite.

Te dejo un completo [Tutorial SQLite Android](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/10/android-sqlite-bases-de-datos/)

Comment: Bueno, no hay de otra XD, aprendere a utilizar el gestor de base de datos SQLite, Gracias por tu respuesta!!

Comment: No es dificil!! esta lleno de información y videos en las comunidades. Saludos! y exito @AlexisRodriguez

Comment: "Android no soporta a MySQL como motor de base de datos" cuidado con esto. Android no lo soporta para instalarlo, pero sí lo soporta como cliente mediante JDBC. El problema con ello es que tu aplicación tendría que estar en la misma red donde esté el servidor RDBMS (MySQL u otro). Usualmente, las aplicaciones no siempre se desarrollan así, por lo que una solución para ello es consumir servicios.

Comment: Me imagino que la aplicación es para el uso de diferentes usuarios con diferentes localidades por ende seria casi imposible que estuvieran conectadas a la misma Red.. Aunque tienes razon que me falto la frase "para instalarlo"

Answer (score 3):

Lo más recomendado es separar tu lógica en backend y frontend, como si una aplicación web se tratase, para ello te sugiero una opción y es el consumo de servicios Web a través del estilo de arquitectura [REST](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer), te dejo este [tutorial](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/10/servicio-web-restful-android-php-mysql-json/) muy completo donde viene paso a paso como consumir y montar los web services.

Parecerá un poco tedioso al inicio pero una vez tengas configurado todo, extender tus peticiones será bastante sencillo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, investigare sobre ello aver que honda. Saludos!!

Comment: claro, cualquier duda aquí está la comunidad...